# Forked repository to standalone

Tags: github, git-fork

I created a forked GitHub repo of WordPress plugin, fixed many things and finally overtaken the plugin. Thats why I would love to make my forked repo as a standalone repository (with issues and possibility to fork etc.). How can I do that and keep all the changes already done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GitHub actually has a wiki page about that topic: [Duplicating a repository](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository/).

Basically, you clone the old repository to your PC

```
git clone https://github.com/you/old-repository
```

and then do a mirror-push to the new location

```
cd old-repository
git push --mirror https://github.com/you/new-repository
```

If you don't want to create a new repo with a different name, you might have to delete the fork before the mirror-push.